# How does threading save time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I am learning threading in C#. However, I can't understand that which aspects of threads are actually improving performance.

Consider a scenario where there only a single core processor exists. Splitting your task into multiple threads uses the same process context (shared resource) and they run simultaneously. As the threads are just sharing time, how come their run time (turnaround time) is less than a single threaded process?

Comment: threading is most efficient in multi core environments

Comment: Consider another scenario, still on a single-core processor: you're downloading a large file from a website. It's very likely that the operation will take a while and won't fully use the CPU. A thread allows you to use the spare CPU time for other tasks.

Comment: Think of it this way, if you had to test 'X' thing, would you be able to do it faster by yourself?  Or would it be much quicker if you and a few other people were all doing it?

Comment: Your application might be waiting for something other than the CPU - such as data being transferred over a network, or loading a file from the hard disk. In this case it may make sense to have this happen in another thread rather than block the main thread in your application.

Comment: "As the threads are just sharing time, how come their run time (turnaround time) is less than a single threaded process"? The turnaround time is **longer**. Having more threads allows you to do work while another thread is sleeping waiting for notification to wake up (such as is the case when you do synchronous IO), but by having more threads, you're creating extra work for your OS/runtime.

Comment: This question might also be of interest to you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80424/why-using-more-threads-makes-it-slower-than-using-less-threads

Comment: One of many scenario - Stuff that not matters much to your client can be threaded like, **Send mails to client for confirmation on click of submit**. Just give a thread to your mailer function and let response go to client. Why client should wait for SMTP server to process/send (other I/O) email, let him play with web page. _Applicable to Single Core too_

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Consider a scenario where there only a single core processor exists. Splitting your task into multiple threads uses the same process context (shared resource) and they run simultaneously. As the threads are just sharing time, how come their run time (turnaround time) is less than a single threaded process?

You are entirely correct to be skeptical of any claimed speedup here.

First off, as Servy and others point out in their answers, if the jobs are not *processor bound* then clearly there can be some speedups here because *while the processor is idle waiting for the disk or the network to come back, it could be doing the work of another thread*.

But let's suppose you have two processor-bound tasks, a single processor, and either two threads or one thread.  In the one-thread scenario it goes like this:

- Do 100% of the work of job 1. Suppose this takes 1000 ms.
- Do 100% of the work of job 2. Suppose this takes 1000 ms.

Total time: two seconds. Total jobs done: two.  But here's the important bit:  **the client that was waiting for job 1 got their job done in only one second.** The client that was waiting for job 2 had to wait two seconds.

Now if we have two threads and one CPU it goes like this:

- Do 10% of the work of job 1, for 100 ms.
- Do 10% of the work of job 2, for 100 ms.
- Do 10% of the work of job 1
- Do 10% of the work of job 2
  ...

Again, total time two seconds, but this time **the client that was waiting for job 1 got their job done in 1.9 seconds, nearly 100% slower than the one-thread scenario!**

So that's the moral of the story here, that you are entirely correct to point out.  If the following conditions are met:

- The jobs are CPU-bound
- There are more threads than CPUs
- The work is useful only for its end result

Then **adding more threads only slows you down**.

Libraries such as the Task Parallel Library are designed for this scenario; they try to figure out when adding more threads will make things worse, and try to only schedule as many threads as there are CPUs to serve them.

Now, if any of those conditions are *not* met then adding more threads is a good idea.

- If the jobs are not CPU bound then adding more threads allows the CPU to do work when it would otherwise be idle, waiting for network or disk.
- If there are idle CPUs then adding more threads allows those CPUs to be scheduled.
- If partially-computed results are useful then adding more threads improves the situation because there are more opportunities for clients to consume partially-computed results. In our second scenario, for instance, the clients of *both* jobs are getting partial results every 200 milliseconds, which is *fair*.

Answer (score 28):

In a single core CPU the advantage that you get is through asynchrony.  Using threads is one way of achieving that (although not the only way).

Imagine the process for cooking a meal.  Which do you think is faster:

1. Start some water boiling.  Wait for it to finish.
2. Add some noodles.  Wait for them to finish being cooked.
3. Wash/prep some vegetables.
4. Stir fry the vegetables.
5. Put on plate and serve.

Or instead:

1. Start some water boiling.
2. While the water is boiling wash/prep some vegetables.
3. Add some noodles to the pot of boiling water.
4. Stir fry the vegetables while the noodles are being cooked.
5. Put on plate and serve.

From my experiences, the second is quicker.

The general idea here is that in many situations when programming you will have an operation that takes some time, but it doesn't require work from the CPU to be completed.  A common example is IO.  When you send a request off to the database to go get some information it's common for there to be other things for you to do while you wait for that request to come back.  Perhaps you can send several requests and then wait for them to finish, rather than starting one, waiting on it, then starting the next, waiting, and so on (although sometimes you have to do the latter).

Now, if the work that you need to do is CPU bound work then you'll really only get benefits out of threading if you have multiple cores on your CPU such that work can actually be done in parallel, and not just asynchronously.  For example, a lot of graphics related work (multiplying matrices, to give a simple example) often involves doing a *lot* of basic math.  If you have several cores these operations often scale very well.  If you don't have multiple cores (or a GPU, which is effectively a CPU with a *lot* of very small and simple cores) there isn't much point in using threads.

Comment: I would add that threads are a common way of achieving asynchrony (despite their relatively high cost), because they tend to be much simpler than the alternative (callbacks). There are some languages that attempt to make this difference smaller, like C# 5.0 or Go.

Comment: @Servy- Nice example, It would explain scenario better if you had single hob stove and doing non stove dependent task in parallel. though you've made the point clear, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the comments you have are correct, but I'll throw my two cents out as well (and list the comments in here):

Jonesy: "threading is most efficient in multi core environments" -> Yes, but this is a single core cpu...so I'll come back to this.

KooKiz and John Sibly: They both mention I/O.  Your machine is not crunching along at full power 100% of the time.  There are quite a lot of other things happening that take up time, and during those events, your CPU gets to take a break.

(point of reference: I/O can be network transmission, hard disk/RAM read, SQL query, etc.  Anything that brings in new data to the CPU or offloads data FROM the CPU)

These breaks are time that your cpu can be doing other things.  If you have a single core cpu (we'll ignore hyperthreading at the moment), and a single-thread application, then it runs happy as can be.  It does not, however, run constantly.  CPU scheduling will give it a cycle or two, then move on to something else, then after a while come back to your program, give it a few more cycles, move on, etc.  This gives the ILLUSION of being able to do "multiple things at once" on a single core cpu.

Now, since this is a normal program and not some insanely small assembly program where you are writing values to the cache directly, your program stores data in RAM...a relatively slow storage medium compared to the CPU cache.  Because of this, loading values takes time.

During this time, it is possible that your CPU has nothing better to do.  This is where you can see a speedup on a multi-threaded application, even on a single core.  The other thread will fill in those extra CPU cycles, where the CPU would otherwise be idle.

Note that it is highly unlikely that you will see a 2:1 speedup.  It is much more likely that your 2-threaded program will only see a 10-20% speed boost, if that.  Remember, the "other" thread (which at any given point is the thread that is NOT performing I/O) will only really be running at its full capacity while the first thread is performing I/O.

Frequently, however, you can actually see a WORSE time.  This is because your CPU now has to spend more time switching between the threads in your process (remember, we can only run one thing at a time!).  This is called *overhead*.  The second thread creates more overhead than it can make up for, and so the process overall slows down.

On a multicore machine, you have two physical executors...which means the second thread gets an entire new core to work with.  This means that it doesn't have to compete with as many other things for execution time.  Therefore, we get a substantial speedup here.

Then of course you have multiprocess programs that execute over a cluster, but we'll save that for another time.

Comment: Can RAM read be considered I/O here? As far as I know, it's fast enough so that context switch while waiting for the read doesn't make sense (probably with the exception of HyperThreading, but you said to ignore that).

Comment: @svick: Typical consumer RAM operates at what, 7-10 ms? a whole lot of cycles can happen in that amount of time.  I honestly don't know if the context switch happens, but I would suspect so.  According to http://askldjd.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/length-of-a-thread-quantum/ , a quantum for that particular cpu is around 5 ms...which is 13 million cpu cycles.  Given those numbers, I would assume that RAM counts as IO, as you can be giving up up to 2 or more full quantums just to get a variable.

Comment: I thought [DRAM operates on the order of tens of *nanoseconds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency). Tens of milliseconds is the latency of HDDs.

Comment: @svick: Apologies, you are correct.  Even so, you still lose 13 thousand cycles.  In this case, I don't know if that is considered acceptable loss or not, and so therefore counts as I/O

Answer (score 2):

If computation is divided into concurrent threads of control, this changes the turnaround times.

#### Example 1: threads making it worse

Suppose that we would like to carry out two calculations, that take 10 minutes each.

If we schedule these consecutively (no multithreading), then in 10 minutes we will have the result from one calculation, and in another 10 minutes, we will have the result from the other calculation.

If we time slice betweeen the computations, then we will have to wait 20 minutes, upon the passage of which, we suddenly get both results.

#### Example 2: threads making it better

Suppose that we would like to carry out two calculations. One will take a minute and the other 59 minutes, **but we do not know this**. (Remember, we are just a scheduler which does not understand code.)

If we just run the two jobs one by one, it could happen that the 59 minute job is scheduled first. So then we have to wait 59 minutes for one result, and then one more minute for the second result. Basically an hour's wait for both results.

If we are lucky, we end up running the shorter job first, and get the first result in 1 minute and the second one 59 minutes later: a much better average turnaround time.

But suppose we time slice between the jobs with threads. Then we get the results of the first job in 2 minutes, and the second one 58 minutes later.  This is almost as good as the second scenario, but without the need to predict which job will be the short one.

**Threading with time slicing for purely CPU-bound tasks helps to avoid pathological cases, where a really large job delays everything else by the full time required to complete that large job.**

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that threading won't inherently make a process faster - sometimes, competing for the same process will increase necessary runtime instead of reducing it. A good assessment to make is whether or not your desired scenario will benefit from multithreading in the first place.

The basic gist of threading is to multitask with available resources - as KooKiz notes, much like using leftover CPU time when available. But you're right, there can be instances where the use of threading won't improve runtime.

However, even for single core systems, there are instances where multithreading *can* improve performance. When one process is waiting for something, it doesn't lock out any other processes running in tandem. Depending on how long the wait takes place, your single core could jump between other independent processes to, on the whole, save time.

Answer (score 0):

You are entirely correct that using multiple threads on a single-core CPU won't improve the *total CPU time*. In fact, it could make it worse, due to the [price of context switching](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html).

But the total CPU time is only half of the story...

### Fluid UI

Threads are also one way of achieving *asynchrony*, which is especially important for *fluid user interface*. For example, if you do an expensive CPU-bound processing and handle the UI on the same thread, your program will appear (from the user's perspective) to temporarily "hang" until the processing is done. But if you push the processing to a background thread, the UI thread can keep responding to user's input and/or keep informing the user of the progress.

### Non-CPU-Bound Processing

On top of that, not all processing is CPU-bound. If you do something like reading a file, accessing a database or calling a web service, the thread will be blocked (and the CPU underutilized) while waiting for the external resource. If there are other threads that need to do some work, they can use the CPU cycles while the first thread is blocked.

### TPL

In case of C#, you probably want to use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for concurrency (and [async-await](/questions/tagged/async-await) for asynchrony), instead of trying to manage the low-level threads yourself. By default, [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)s will be scheduled on the thread pool, avoiding the danger of having too many threads (and context switches).

Take a look at [Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx) for more info.