# Timer makes my application lags

Tags: c#

Well, I've got list of objects (picture boxes) with 30 objects which have location same as players in the game I'm playing. Players positions change fast,so positions of my picture boxes should change too.
I've tried to do this using timer,but application lags,and it looks like players are warping.
Is there any other way to change objects' positions on the form fast,without lagging?If not,maybe some suggestions what to do to prevent lag?

Comment: Using a single picture box and redrawing the frame would probably be better performance-wise, rather than having many picture boxes. But ultimately I think WinForms is not really the right framework to use to create a responsive game...

Comment: Oh,I'm not trying to create a game.I'm making a tool for an already existed game.

Comment: As I was enlightened in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29374892/833335
C#'s async-await mechanism would probably be the best to use

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading this tutorial by MSDN on threading. Threading allows you to improve the performance of your program by make more use of your CPU.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Hope it helps

Edit: You can also use a background worker which makes threading slightly easier.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx